# Rake tasks, "warning: already initialized constant STATS_DIRECTORIES"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

when executing the rake tasks, it issues this message:

***warning: already initialized constant STATS_DIRECTORIES***

¿how can I load it, using rails 4?.

thanks for you help.

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions without looking at the code.
Do you have a variable named `STATS_DIRECTORIES`?

Comment: You may want to include the stack trace and the file to which it refers.

Comment: when executing 'rake db: migrate: status' and any 'rake' task, the message it issues at the beginning is:

**/home/<user_name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake:4: warning: already initialized constant STATS_DIRECTORIES**

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue,  When creating the Rails project, the Rakefile is:

Comment: `load 'rails/tasks/statistics.rake'`
In my case i do not need this line "load 'rails/tasks/statistics.rake'", However i just 
leave these lines in my Rakefile:
`require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks`. This is for Rails 4. Thank you for your attention